# Is there a way to filter json data format field in strapi?

Tags: strapi

Hi Guys I'm trying to filter post with data json format field?

```
"categoryList": ["cat", "cat1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for a solution, this is what I have done for a json type field called **tags** of a collection type called **Articles**.

I have two articles in the database with one article having the following values set:

```
title: "lorem ipsum 1",
tags: [
  "test",
  "rest"
]
```

The other article has the following values set:

```
title: "lorem ipsum 2",
tags: [
  "test",
  "graphql"
]
```

My graphql query looks like this:

```
query {
  articlesByTag(limit: 2, where: {tags_include: ["test", "rest"]}, start: 0, sort: "title:asc") {
    title,
    tags
  }
}
```

While my rest query looks like this:

```
http://localhost:1337/articlesByTag?limit=2&tags_include[]=test&tags_include[]=rest
```

This is my articles.js service file:

```js
const { convertRestQueryParams, buildQuery } = require('strapi-utils');
const _ = require('lodash');
const { convertToParams, convertToQuery } = require('../../../node_modules/strapi-plugin-graphql/services/utils');

module.exports = {
  async findByTag(ctx) {
    let tags_include;

    if (ctx.where && ctx.where.tags_include && ctx.where.tags_include.length > 0) {
      tags_include = ctx.where.tags_include;
      delete ctx.where.tags_include;
    } else if (ctx.query && ctx.query.tags_include && ctx.query.tags_include.length > 0) {
      tags_include = ctx.query.tags_include;
      delete ctx.query.tags_include;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(tags_include)) {
      tags_include = [tags_include];
    }

    let filters = null;

    if (ctx.query) {
      filters = convertRestQueryParams({
        ...convertToParams(ctx.query)
      });
    } else {
      filters = convertRestQueryParams({
        ...convertToParams(_.pick(ctx, ['limit', 'start', 'sort'])),
        ...convertToQuery(ctx.where),
      });
    }

    const entities = await strapi.query('articles').model.query(qb => {

      buildQuery({ model: strapi.query('articles').model, filters: filters })(qb);

      if (tags_include.length > 0) {
        tags_include.forEach((tag) => {
          if (tag && tag.length > 0) {
            const likeStr = `%"${tag}"%`;
            qb.andWhere('tags', 'like', likeStr);
          }
        });
      }

    }).fetchAll();

    return entities;
  },
};
```

This is the entry needed in routes.js

```
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/articlesByTag",
      "handler": "articles.findByTag",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
```

This is the controller articles.js

```js
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  async findByTag(ctx) {
    const entities = await strapi.services.articles.findByTag(ctx);

    return entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.articles }));
  },
};
```

And finally this is the schema.graphql.js

```js
module.exports = {
  query: `
    articlesByTag(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Articles]
  `,
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      articlesByTag: {
        description: 'Return articles filtered by tag',
        resolverOf: 'application::articles.articles.findByTag',
        resolver: async (obj, options, ctx) => {
          return await strapi.api.articles.controllers.articles.findByTag(options);
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to filter the JSON fields yet as of beta.17.8 (latest)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like that?

```
strapi.query('cool_model').find({ categoryList: { $all: [ "cat" , "cat1" ] } })
```

Comment: is this for models > Posts.js? @mikek

Comment: Custom controller - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers